# MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    news_posts
WHERE
    user_id = ?
        AND id NOT IN (SELECT 
            post_id
        FROM
            user_read
        WHERE
            user_id = ?)
```

I want to make it more "eloquent". I've tried the following, but its (obviously) not working:

```
NewsPost::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->whereNotIn(function ($query) {
        $query->DB::table('user_read')
            ->select('post_id')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    })->get();
```

Comment: With you're `WhereNotIn` method you haven't provided a column name. What should it be? Also, I'm assuming you're getting an error with: `$query->DB::table`

Comment: @RossWilson  Yes. Thank you! =) got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies! Got it working with the following tweaks:

```
 NewsPost::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) {
                $query->select('post_id')
                ->from('user_read')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 'where' method is executing a simple SQL query on 'new_posts' table. Can you try to rewrite this query and let mysql do the filtering for new posts? (search for LEFT OUTER JOIN on mysql)

```
SELECT *
FROM news_posts a
JOIN user_read b
ON a.id = b.post_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
AND b.post_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Well, I dont think joining them is what I want to do. I want to remove all posts from user_read from news_posts. Thus leaving only unread posts...if that makes sense...

Comment: Please see https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for 'Left Oute Join'.